# Did Michael Jai White really puncture the bag by a kick?

Tags: character, never-back-down-2

*Never Back Down 2: The Beatdown* contains a scene where **Michael Jai White** punctures a bag full of sand with just one kick.

Michael Jai White has a history of training in martial arts, specially in Kyokushin Karate. Given his training and physique his kicks must be powerful; but are they powerful enough to puncture a punching bag in one kick?

Comment: Few bags are filled with sand anymore (at least thats my understanding), so this is probably a prop or prepared bag, especially considering the puncture occurs off-camera (although maybe thats for effect). But, punctures are not only possible, but actually common, when a bag is old and the stuffing is compressed, as it appears to be in this shot

Comment: That being said, I'm sure MJW could kick a hole through that bag and into one of those kids if he really wanted to

Comment: @Dpeif: I am aware of his capability but am looking for some real sources or behind the scenes.

Comment: From the scene my best guess is that he didn't. There is a camera cut before he sets up for his kick and then the kick occurs on the unseen side of the bag, after which it turns and we see sand pouring out. They could easily have cut the bag first and then had him kick it. That said I don't know for sure, this is just me guessing. I would think if they wanted to show him really doing it then they would have made sure to show the breaking actually occur on camera.